Bigtable Error : Batcher was not closed properly
java.lang.RuntimeException: Batcher allocation site at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.batching.BatcherImpl$BatcherReference.<init>(BatcherImpl.java:542) at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.api.gax.batching.BatcherImpl.<init>(BatcherImpl.java:205) at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.EnhancedBigtableStub.newMutateRowsBatcher(EnhancedBigtableStub.java:680) at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient.newBulkMutationBatcher(BigtableDataClient.java:1113) at com.google.bigtable.repackaged.com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient.newBulkMutationBatcher(BigtableDataClient.java:1080) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.wrappers.veneer.DataClientVeneerApi.createBulkMutation(DataClientVeneerApi.java:75) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BigtableBufferedMutatorHelper.<init>(BigtableBufferedMutatorHelper.java:83) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase.BatchExecutor.<init>(BatchExecutor.java:145) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase2_x.BigtableAsyncTable.getBatchExecutor(BigtableAsyncTable.java:101) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase2_x.BigtableAsyncTable.asyncRequests(BigtableAsyncTable.java:232) at com.google.cloud.bigtable.hbase2_x.BigtableAsyncTable.delete(BigtableAsyncTable.java:227) at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.AsyncTable.deleteAll(AsyncTable.java:550) at com.stl.sciocardio.platform.worker_agent.dataservice.EcgDataService.deleteData(EcgDataService.java:283) at com.stl.sciocardio.platform.worker_agent.dataservice.EcgDataService.deleteAnnotations(EcgDataService.java:247) at com.stl.sciocardio.platform.worker_agent.receiver.WorkerToWorkerAgentMessageReceiver.processMessage(WorkerToWorkerAgentMessageReceiver.java:213) at com.stl.sciocardio.common.pubsub.PubSubMessageReceiver.receiveMessage(PubSubMessageReceiver.java:42) at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageDispatcher$3.run(MessageDispatcher.java:441) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Above mentioned error occurred in all Bigtable connected java modules. But this error occur only when connected to BigTable. When connected to Hbase, there is no error. BigTable-version is 2.9.0. The above asynchronous way is giving RuntimeException as Batcher allocation site. We intend to use asynchronous methods as it is efficient when handling high load. I have provided the code snippet of asynchronous method we used.
public CompletableFuture saveECGData(List data, boolean valid) {
   try {
       Configuration bigtableConfiguration = BigtableConfiguration.asyncConfigure(BigtableConfiguration.configure(projectId, bigTableInstanceId));
       AsyncConnection connection = new BigtableAsyncConnection(bigtableConfiguration);
       AsyncTable table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(tablePrefix + TABLE_DATA));
       List putList = new ArrayList<>();
       String[][] columns = new String[][]{{CF_ECG_DATA, COL_LEAD}, {CF_ECG_DATA, COL_RAW_CHANNEL1},
                   {CF_ECG_DATA, COL_RAW_CHANNEL2}, {CF_MOTION_DATA, COL_MOTION_DATA}};
       for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
           ECGData ecgData = data.get(i);
           String rowKey = ecgData.getId() + ":" + ecgData.getTimestamp();
           rowKey = String.format("%1$25s", rowKey).replace(" ", "0"); //NOSONAR
           Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
           put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(columns[0][0]), Bytes.toBytes(columns[0][1]), BytesConverter.toBytes(ecgData.getLead()));
           putList.add(put);
       }
       return table.putAll(putList);
   } catch (Exception e) {
       LOG.error("Error : ", e);
       return null;
   }

}

While we investigate this issue, we changed the code to synchronous way. At that time, it works perfectly fine without any issues. I have provided the code snippet for this
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.TableName;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Connection;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Put;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Table;
   import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.Bytes;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.util.ArrayList;
   import java.util.List;
   import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;

   public CompletableFuture saveECGData(List data) {
       return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
           try (Connection connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(projectId, bigTableInstanceId)) {
               Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_DATA));
               try {
                   List putList = new ArrayList<>();
                   String[] columnFamilyAndQualifier = {CF_ECG_DATA, COL_LEAD};
                   for (ECGData ecgData : data) {
                       String rowKey = String.format("%1$25s", ecgData.getId() + ":" + ecgData.getTimestamp()).replace(" ", "0");
                       Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
                       put.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamilyAndQualifier[0]), Bytes.toBytes(columnFamilyAndQualifier[1]),             BytesConverter.toBytes(ecgData.getLead()));
                       putList.add(put);
                   }
                   table.put(putList);
                   return null; 
               } catch (IOException e) {
                   LOG.error("Error while writing data to table: ", e);
                   throw new RuntimeException("Failed to save ECG data", e);
               } finally {
                   try {
                       table.close();
                   } catch (IOException e) {
                      LOG.error("Error closing table: ", e);
                   }
               }
          } catch (IOException e) {
               LOG.error("Error connecting to Bigtable: ", e);
               throw new RuntimeException("Failed to connect to Bigtable", e);
           }
       });
   }

In both cases we used same dependencies with same version. When comparing both cases, we could not able to close the table in asynchronous way. We didn't find a way to do that. Is it the reason for this issue or is there any other issue in the implementation?
How we can resolve this issue?
